# How to add custom routing to express when route parameter is certain value

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

### Situation

I have a route which looks like below:

```
router.get('/api/v1/tokens/:token_name', middleware1, middleware2)
```

And it works great for most of the values for `token_name`. Now, I'd like to add handling for a new `token_name` value (let's say it's `token_name: baz`), but this one has a special condition and needs another middleware, let's call it `middleware0`, run before `middleware1` and `middleware2`

### What I've tried

The way I've handled it right now is by adding another route which takes priority over the one above, as seen below:

```
router.get('/api/v1/tokens/baz', middleware0, middleware1, middleware2)    
router.get('/api/v1/tokens/:token_name', middleware1, middleware2)
```

But now I don't have access to the `token_name` variable in the other middlewares, which is necessary for them to do their logic.

### Question

Is there a way to solve this using only the express router, and not adding any code to the middlewares? Like, to match a specific value, but also add it as a variable?

Comment: You can make a condition in `middleware0` like `if 'baz' then do this ` and if not then return as it is.

Comment: Is `baz` a special value for `token_name`? Like, if `token_name` is equal to `baz` then there will be some operation in `middleware0`?

Comment: @ShamsNahid yes that's the case

Answer (score 1):

You can use single route with conditional execution of your `middleware0`, Something like below

```
const middleware0 = (req, res, next) => {
  if (req.params.token_name !== 'baz') {
     next();
     return;
  }
  // actual middleware code handling request
};

router.get('/api/v1/tokens/:token_name', middleware0, middleware1, middleware2);
```

Comment: This is what I ended up going with, it just felt a little "off" to me because it encapsulated what is essentially routing logic into the middleware, but I'll accept this answer if there's nothing else that comes through soon